# IE9 (ie) Compatibility mode is breaking "select"

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is a real head scratcher for me. Our site (amyadele.com/labels/holiday-and-seasonal/…), has a price drop down in the right hand sidebar. In every browser except IE, the pricing drop down works. When you view it in ie, the drop down does not show anything. I used i9 just recently, and if I force ie9 out of compatibility mode, the drop down works.

Does anybody know a solution to this, or see what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Just wondering, how do you force ie out of it?

Comment: Note: I deleted my comments here and made them into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your DOCTYPE tag from

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Also, don't confuse Browser Mode and Document Mode. In IE if you F12 (Developer tools) and try different combinations from the 2 menus once the page is loaded. Your 'select' works fine for me with Browser Mode: 'IE9 Compat View' and Document Mode: anything other than Quirks.

Answer (score 1):

[Force IE into standards mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx) by starting the document with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and out of compatibility mode by adding [`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx) in the `<head>`.

Seriously, in Quirks mode a browser is basically allowed to draw a sad kitten instead of your website.

Comment: compatibility mode != quirks mode. But +1 anyway, because this is the correct solution.

Comment: to clarify: quirks mode is effectively an IE5-fallback mode, which is triggered if you don't have a doctype. Compatibility mode is an IE7 or IE8 fallback mode, which is triggered either by explicitly requesting it with a version number in the `X-UA-Compatible` tag, or by the browser's config. The config is overridden by the meta tag, so specifying `Edge` as per the answer will prevent the brower going into compatibility mode. Gosh, I hate IE for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: @Spudley You could argue that "standards mode" of an old IE is effectively quirks mode. Added the distinction in the answer.